# how to add class to cell using jquery

Tags: jquery, cell, addclass

I try to class to cell but i got the erroe .please correct my code

> TypeError: table.rows[rowscount].cells[0].addClass is not a function

```
table.rows[rowscount].cells[0].addClass("txtwidth");
```

Comment: `$(table.rows[rowscount].cells[0]).addClass("txtwidth");`

Comment: you have to use the *addClass* function with a jquery object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) is a function provided by jQuery, so it needs to be called in the jQuery wrapper object instead you are trying to invoke it using a dom element reference

It is a messy solution

```
$(table.rows[rowscount].cells[0]).addClass("txtwidth");
```

or

```
$(table).find('tr:eq(' + rowscount+') td:first-child').addClass("txtwidth");
```

Answer (score 2):

You're addressing the DOM element instead of the jQuery object.

```
$(table.rows[rowscount].cells[0]).addClass("txtwidth");
```